# how to use asciitable.vim to show ascii table in gvim console?

Tags: vim

I have downloaded `ascii.table` and save it in `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin`,
there is a description.

```
Mappings are made to:
<leader>a, <leader>a8, <leader>a10, <leader>ax, and <leader>a16.
```

When I input `:<leader>a`  in command mode, there is no effect. How can I call ascii table in my gvim console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are mappings, not commands.

`<leader>` is a placeholder for the leader key as defined by the `mapleader` option. This key acts like a namespace, allowing you to create many custom mappings outside of the defaults. See `:help mapleader` for more information.

If you or one of your plugins didn't change its value, it is automatically set to `\` so you are supposed to hit `\a`, `\a8` and so on.

Also, you placed that script in the wrong place, it should be:

- in `c:\Documents and Settings\<username>\vimfiles\plugin\` on XP
- or `c:\Users\<username>\vimfiles\plugin\` on Vista, 7 and 8.

As well as any downloaded script. Don't touch `C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\`.

Comment: Did you read my answer at all? `\a` is not a command, it's a mapping. Try `\a` in normal mode or insert mode, as indicated in your plugin's doc or README.